# Spring Boot Filtering the results based on logged user

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, authorization

I've developed a solution based on Spring Boot. It's like 10 projects with many endpoints, and I'm using Eureka and Zuul too.

Now I'm dealing with the security issues I have to solve. Authentication and Authorization will be done using spring-security in the Zuul server plus annotations to the endpoints.

But one thing I don't know is how to filter the results based on who's logged in. In my case, I need to associate each user* to an entity called Enterprise. Then I have the entity FooBar that have a FK_ID column that associates to an Enterprise. When this user logs in and call the listAllFooBars endpoint it should answer only those associated to the Enterprise object associated to the user.

The same validation should happen during POST and PUT calls...

How to implement that??

'* by user I mean the pair name+password

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the use case of @PostFilter annotation from spring security. You can have expression that  filters the collection based on current authentication object.

Comment: Is that the best practice while working with the Spring framework?

Comment: It's better to pass the current user ID into sql query to use as filter, but if you can't - then use @postfilter